# Drag and drop differences between Godot 3 and 4?

Tags: gui, ui-design, godot-4, godot-3

I'd been following Godot tutorials to add Drag & Drop functionality to `Control` nodes. They've presumably been created for Godot 3.x, but my project is 4.0. And I can't seem to get it to work, thinking something has changed.

To make sure it's due to the difference in Godot versions, I did the exact same steps to reproduce the situation in both Godot 4.0 and 3.5.1:

1. Create new project, all default settings
2. Add `Node2D` root scene
3. Add a `PanelContainer` child to that
4. Add a `TextureRect` child to that, and drag the Godot icon resource on it for testing
5. Attach a new script to `PanelContainer` with this code:

   ```
    extends PanelContainer

    func get_drag_data(_position):
        var preview = TextureRect.new()
        preview.texture = $TextureRect.texture
        set_drag_preview(preview)
        return { id = "foobar" }
   ```
6. Run the game

The results:

- In 3.5.1, as expected, you can drag around the Godot icon;
- In 4.0, nothing happens, dragging the icon around won't work;

**What am I missing? How to get dragging of nodes working in version 4.x?**

I've tried a few extra things to answer my own question:

- [Search the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Godot+4.0+get_drag_data), but at the time of writing it seems to give results that are 3.x-specific;
- Go through the node's "Inspector" properties, especially `Mouse` properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nearly discarded my question because I found the answer myself, but perhaps just posting it will help others running into the same gotcha...

If you look at the official documentation for both versions, there's a *tiny* but all-important difference:

- [v3.5 docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-get-drag-data): `Variant get_drag_data ( Vector2 position ) virtual`
- [v4.0 docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-get-drag-data): `Variant _get_drag_data ( Vector2 at_position ) virtual const`

So **in v4.x there is an `_` (underscore) prefix to the method** that wasn't there in 3.x.

The godot engine source code even have [a rename map entry](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/8b1568af70eea62e34267ee4949170d7e2c4faa0/editor/renames_map_3_to_4.cpp#L306) for this change, presumably to help with converting projects? For reference: see [the commit that introduced this change](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/commit/7ff135b0158e0b5dd7a85d98aecd7ff0975e7e43#diff-8d59997c7ead8892d2d7345323c491493cdc8de6d4a54520b91390a1be9d45d5).

Comment: I think it's worth leaving this up & voted accordingly. As more projects pivot from 3 into 4, this sort of thing is bound to trip some folk up. The (unenforced) convention is for virtual function to have have a leading underscore, so this might be a case of the update bringing the API in line with their own [guidelines](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_styleguide.html). Reminder: remember to circle back & mark this is a the accepted answer as it helps others. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! That makes sense. - The system allows you to accept your own answer after 2 days, will try to remember to do so.